# Codeception ->see("String") fails but ->seeInSource("String") succeeds

Tags: codeception

Something is wrong with the `AcceptanceTester->see()` method for me. It can't see things that are plainly there in the source, as shown by the `AcceptanceTester->seeInSource()` method.

Here's my test, which runs in `PHPBrowser` within the `WP-Browser` implementation of Codeception:

```php
    public function testAfricaIsVisible(AcceptanceTester $I) {
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
        $I->seeInSource('Africa');
        $I->see('Africa');
    }
```

Here's the result I get:

[image: screenshot of results, showing the ->see() test failing]

As you can see, `->SeeInSource("Africa")` works, but `->see("Africa")` fails.

I understand that [`->SeeInSource()` sometimes "sees" things that `->see()` doesn't](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#see), but in this case, the word "Africa" is link text that should be clearly visible with or without `strip_tags()` applied.

In this case, when I open up the `Html` link the word "Africa" is clearly visible:

[image: screenshot showing how "africa" is on the page as the text of an a tag]

**Anyone have any idea why Codeception doesn't `->see()` this text?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone with a similar problem, the underlying issue was malformed HTML that was glossed over by Chrome/Firefox but screwed up the site as seen by `Phpbrowser`. I bet if I was using the `WebDriver` module instead, it would work.

**The solution:  Use an HTML validation tool and fix the reported syntax errors.**

In this case it was a `title` tag with a single-quote in it, e.g. `title='doesn't'`